# openldap make sure password does not contain username

Tags: linux, ldap, authentication, openldap

Is there a way using openldap to ensure that a user's password does not contain their name or their username?

I know that you can use the ppolicy overlay pwdCheckModule by writing a C function to do password checking, but is this the best approach? It doesn't seem like many folks are doing password quality checking this way--the only example I've found is [a github example](https://github.com/onyxpoint/ppolicy-check-password) which only does basic checking.

Answer (score 0):

It's not only the best approach, it's the only approach.